# Mule Logs not showing

Tags: log4j, esb, mule

I'm trying to launch a Mule application I have written, but I cant seem to get the logs to show up when I run it from the console. When I look at the log file, I see the Mule loading process (assuming I am using the app not the service mode) but then the log goes blank. Note that the log is visible when I'm using Mule Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Which files can you find in $MULE_HOME/logs? Assuming you are using Mule 3, there's normally the main one, `mule.log` and the app ones, `mule-app-$APP_NAME`.

Comment: How do you emit logs from your application? How do you start Mule?

Comment: I emit logs from both java code in the components and from logger xml tabs. (like so:   <logger message="#[payload]" level="ERROR" />  )

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your app logging configuration overrides the global one, but is also not doing what you expect. Add -M-Dlog4j.debug switch to the Mule command line to see where rogue log4j config file might be coming from.

Answer (score 0):

To properly log Mule messages into a log file, you should have a category definition in your log4j.properties and refer to that in your Mule flow as:

```
<logger level="INFO" category="your_custom_category" message="#[payload]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the entire machine. It sounds like an Eclipse problem not a problem with your program.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not properly placed the properties file and jar file.

Place 
"log4j.properties" in "WEB-INF/classes"

and copy

log4jx.y.z.jar to "WEB-INF/lib".